# Stanford NER - Increase probability for a certain class

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm new to machine learning so I apologize if this question is silly. I'm using Stanford NER's english 4class classifier with good results. However, since my dataset is mostly focused on organizations, I think the results could be improved if I could boost the probability for an entity to be an organization to the detriment of other classes.(Ex: I would prefer "Carl Zeis" to be identified as an organization rather than a person). Is my supposition correct?  If so, can it be achieved in an easier way than retraining the model?

Comment: After posting this question, I realized that http://datascience.stackexchange.com is probably a more suited place to ask it, so here is the link to the question and answer: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10412/stanford-ner-increase-probability-for-a-certain-class